# Не посылает запрос JQuery Ajax в JS

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, json

Здравствуйте.
Такая проблема, не посылается запрос autocomplete на выполнение сервлета, смотрю через стандартный Chrome инструментарий.

**add.jsp**

```html
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
   <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function() {
                $("input#entity_book").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url : "/SearchBook",

                            data: {
                                term: request.term
                            },
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                response(data);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                    },
                    open: function () {
                    },
                    close: function () {
                    }

                });
            });

        </script>
        <input  type="text" class="input_field" maxlength="500" name="Entity[book]" id="Entity_book">
```

**web.xml**

```html
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SearchBook</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ajax.SearchBook</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SearchBook</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/searchbook</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: у вас регистр id в селекторе неверный

Comment: @zb', поменял, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Приведите в порядок регистры: `Entity_book` в *add.jsp* и `"/SearchBook"` в *add.jsp* vs `/searchbook` в *web.xml*

Comment: @br3t , привел, но ноль реакции, все ещё молчит - не посылает запроса

Comment: Нет ли ошибок в консоли? js правильный и рабочий: http://joxi.ru/J2bewQBIXyX6dm

Comment: @br3t , ошибок в консоли не было, но сейчас вдруг начала работать, убрал одну строчку перед этим, которая дает путь до файлов ресурса проекта. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `$("input#Entity_book")` вместо `$("input#entity_book")`

Comment: Не помогло, по-моему тут без разницы.

Comment: У вас не указан тип передачи данных - попробуйте в ajax-запросе после url : "/SearchBook",  дописать - type: "POST" или type: "GET" в зависимости о того как высылаете данные

Comment: Без изменений, хоть POST, хоть GET пробовал ещё ранее.